# Handle event gives error about withevent on sub routine

Tags: .net, events, handle

I'm getting a error from click event that used to be fine. Here's the sub call:

```
 Private Sub frmNewSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles frmNewSave.Click
```

This used to work fine and I don't know what I did to the code to get this error.

Any clues? 
Also, if any of this is not clear, just let me know and I will try again.
TIA

Answer (score 0):

Ok... figured out how to fix this. What happened that caused the error was a one of my controls name got changed (have no idea how). So all I needed to do was rename the control name to match the spot where the error is generated.

Thanks for looking